# Is there a need to return on unittest in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, return

From http://pythontesting.net/framework/unittest/unittest-introduction/

```
import unittest
from unnecessary_math import multiply

class TestUM(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_numbers_3_4(self):
        self.assertEqual( multiply(3,4), 12)

    def test_strings_a_3(self):
        self.assertEqual( multiply('a',3), 'aaa')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But is there a need to return at the end of each unittest function? If so, what's the use of that? e.g.:

```
import unittest
from unnecessary_math import multiply

class TestUM(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_numbers_3_4(self):
        self.assertEqual( multiply(3,4), 12)
        return 

    def test_strings_a_3(self):
        self.assertEqual( multiply('a',3), 'aaa')
        return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to return `None` explicitly, since a function without return statement always return `None` by default. Besides there is no need to return anything from a unittest, since there's no receiver of that output and it doesn't serve any purpose anyway.

Comment: Sometimes returning `None` explicitly is... well, more explicit if that `None` is important. Of course, the return statement should be omitted if there's no receiver, like you say.

Comment: @timgeb it makes sense when your function has multiple return statements, or it can return values other than none

Comment: Yes, that's one of the cases I was thinking of.